# To find two sides of a triangle when it is circumscribed a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, problem-solving

A triangle ABC is drawn to circumscribe a circle
of radius 4 cm such that the segments BD and
DC into which BC is divided by the point of
contact D are of lengths 8 cm and 6 cm
respectively. Find the sides AB
and AC.

[image]

I tried to solve this problem by my way but i failed to do so i need a short and understandable solution of this problem.
Thanks

Comment: how far did you get on your own?

Comment: I used Pythagoras theorem to make linear equations but i got the value of AC and AD 6 and 8 which is not possible.

Comment: @2k0 AD isn't a straight line.

Comment: You can get tan of half the angles at $B$ and $C$ very easily, which gives you the angles at $B$ and $C$ hence at $A$. Then you can use the sine rule to get the missing sides. Trig identities are available to obtain the sines of the angle at $A$ without using tables. There may be an easier way, but this sy=trategy will work.

Comment: OC bisects C. You can thus find C using Pythagoras' theorem, since OD is perpendicular to BC. Same for B. Since the sum of angles in a triangle is 180 degrees, you can find A. Now use the law of sines to find AB and AC.

Comment: @Mark Bennet But AD is perpendicular to BC as a line drawn from center to tangent is perpendicular to tangent i.e, OD is perpendicular to BC because BC is tangent to the circle.

Comment: @2k0 OD is, but not AD

Comment: I divided this triangle into three part then i found the area of each triangle and compare it with Heron's formula then i got 7 as an ans.But i found this way of doing this problem very time consumable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Finding the numbers

If all I needed was the answer, I'd simply construct this in e.g. [Cinderella](http://www.cinderella.de/):

[image: Figure]

## Using a formula

If you need a formula, then look at the Wikipedia article on incircles. In the section “[Other incircle properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Other_incircle_properties)” you'll find this:

> Suppose the tangency points of the incircle divide the sides into lengths of $x$ and $y$, $y$ and $z$, and $z$ and $x$. Then the incircle has the radius<sup>[[11]](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle&oldid=635408152#cite_note-11)</sup> $$r=\sqrt{\frac{xyz}{x+y+z}}$$
>
> ---
>
> <sup>[11]</sup> Chu, Thomas, The Pentagon, Spring 2005, p. 45, problem 584.

So you have $r=4,y=8,z=6$ which gives you

\begin{align*}
4^2&=\frac{x\cdot 8\cdot 6}{x+8+6}\\
16(x+14)&=48x \\
x+14&=3x \\
2x&=14 \\
x&=7
\end{align*}

From which you can find $AB=8+x=15$ and $AC=6+x=13$ as in the figure.

## Finding that formula

I haven't read or even found the cited reference, but you could also find that formula using a bit of trigonometry. Start with

$$\tan\angle OAB=\tan\frac\alpha2=\frac{OE}{AE}=\frac rx$$

and similar for the other two half angles. Using the [double angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) for the tangent you get

$$\tan\alpha=\frac{2\frac rx}{1-\left(\frac rx\right)^2}=\frac{2rx}{x^2-r^2}$$

Then using the [formula for angle sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) you get

$$
\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\frac{2rx}{x^2-r^2}+\frac{2ry}{y^2-r^2}}{1-\frac{2rx}{x^2-r^2}\cdot \frac{2ry}{y^2-r^2}}=\frac{2rx(y^2-r^2)+2ry(x^2-r^2)}{(x^2-r^2)(y^2-r^2)-4r^2xy}
%=\frac{2r(x+y)(xy-r^2)}{(xy-rx-ry-r^2)(xy+rx+ry-r^2)}
\\
\tan(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)=\frac{\frac{2rx(y^2-r^2)+2ry(x^2-r^2)}{(x^2-r^2)(y^2-r^2)-4r^2xy}+\frac{2rz}{z^2-r^2}}{1-\frac{2rx(y^2-r^2)+2ry(x^2-r^2)}{(x^2-r^2)(y^2-r^2)-4r^2xy}\cdot\frac{2rz}{z^2-r^2}}
\\=\frac{(2rx(y^2-r^2)+2ry(x^2-r^2))(z^2-r^2)+2rz((x^2-r^2)(y^2-r^2)-4r^2xy)}{((x^2-r^2)(y^2-r^2)-4r^2xy)(z^2-r^2)-(2rx(y^2-r^2)+2ry(x^2-r^2))2rz}
$$

Since $\tan(180°)=0$ you know that the above must be zero, which means that its numerator must be zero. Factorizing that numerator (using a computer algebra system, e.g. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%20%282rx%28y%5E2-r%5E2%29%2B2ry%28x%5E2-r%5E2%29%29%28z%5E2-r%5E2%29%2B2rz%28%28x%5E2-r%5E2%29%28y%5E2-r%5E2%29-4r%5E2xy%29)), you get

$$ 2\cdot r \cdot (r^{2} - x y - x z - y z) \cdot (r^{2} x +  r^{2} y +  r^{2} z - x y z) = 0 $$

One of these two parentheses must encode the relation we are looking for. To find out which of the two it is, you could consider the special case of the regular triangle, where $x=y=z$. The first parenthesis would lead to $r=\sqrt3x$ which is larger than the incircle. The second has $r=\frac13\sqrt3x$ which fits much better. That second parenthesis can be reformulated to the form stated in Wikipedia.

Comment: i Understood the ans. I have never heard of this formula before.

Comment: @2k0: I added some text about how you might find this formula.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:-**

$\dfrac{1}{2}OD(CB+BA+AC)=\sqrt{S(S-AC)(S-CB)(S-BA)}$

> $$S=\dfrac{CB+BA+AC}{2}$$

Comment: I used this formula but it is so time consumable.

Comment: @2k0: You should use the conditions (refer to MvG's figure) $CD=CF$, $DB=BE$ and $FA=AE$. Then I think it won't be much time consuming.